# .htaccess rewrite css/js/images to subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I actually thought there should already be a thread about this but i wasn't able to find one.

let's say i have a website with this structure:

```
/index.php
/.htaccess
/template
/template/css
/template/css/foo.css
```

I'm redirecting everything to index.php with .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?0=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now I've got a problem with the css. that i could fix by placing another .htaccess in /template with this

```
RewriteEngine off
Options -Indexes
```

And then access the css file with http://example.com/template/css/foo.css but actually i would prefere to have just http://example.com/css/foo.css

So i tried to put in /.htaccess the following code (that didn't worked). What did i do wrong?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/css/(.*) www/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/js/(.*) www/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?0=$1 [QSA,L]
```

*note I don't have any .htaccess in /template!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the htaccess file in the css folder. You just need to exclude rewrites to the template directory. You can do it all in a single file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/template/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /template/$1 [L]

RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^/template/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?0=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The first rule handles requests for the css directory, and the second rule is the one you had that routes to index.php except if the request is for template.

Comment: Hi first of all thank you (:

I'm not sure if it's correct to respond here but I don't see where else.

so now i have
index.php
.htaccess
www/
www/css/
www/css/test.css
www/img/
www/js/
www/js/test.js

in .htaccess i have this:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/css/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/css/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/js/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/js/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/img/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/img/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?0=$1 [QSA,L]

What's wrong?